# View Windows Azure Node.js worker role log file

Tags: node.js, logging, azure

I have deployed a Node.js worker role on one of my Azure instances.

On the emulator, I could see the log in the Compute UI, or a locally stored log file. How do I access this file, or the log when deployed on Azure?

Kind of critical for debugging and note crashes, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially write logs and those logs will be written in Azure Table Storage. You add the code to perform logging in the onStart Method of the worker role.

Check out this [SOF ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10475656/649408) and this [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180875.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the way to go! :)

Comment: Any way to route errors to the table as well? Logs can be written, but how I do I know which line unexpectedly crashed my code? Need a view of the error prompt